# How can I check for Python version in a program that uses new language features?

Tags: python, version

If I have a Python script that requires at least a particular
version of Python, what is the correct way to fail gracefully
when an earlier version of Python is used to launch the script?

How do I get control early enough to issue an error message
and exit?

For example, I have a program that uses the ternery operator (new in 2.5) and "with" blocks
(new in 2.6).  I wrote a simple little interpreter-version
checker routine which is the first thing the script would
call ... except it doesn't get that far. Instead, the
script fails during python compilation, before my routines
are even called. Thus the user of the script sees some very
obscure synax error tracebacks - which pretty much require
an expert to deduce that it is simply the case of running
the wrong version of Python.

I know how to check the version of Python. The issue is that some syntax is illegal in older versions of Python. Consider this program:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (2, 4):
    raise "must use python 2.5 or greater"
else:
    # syntax error in 2.4, ok in 2.5
    x = 1 if True else 2
    print x
```

When run under 2.4, I want this result

```
$ ~/bin/python2.4 tern.py 
must use python 2.5 or greater
```

and not this result:

```
$ ~/bin/python2.4 tern.py 
  File "tern.py", line 5
    x = 1 if True else 2
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(Channeling for a coworker.)

Comment: "check the version of python. The issue is that some syntax is illegal in older versions of python."  I don't get how this is a problem.  If you can check the version, you can avoid the syntax error.  How does version checking not apply to syntax?  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: You know that you can get 'with' blocks in Python 2.5 by using `from __future__ import with_statement`.

Comment: @S.Lott Syntax errors mean the interpreter does not understand the structure of the file. They raise exceptions regardless of whether they are inside a conditional.

Comment: @Brendan: While true, one can (1) determine the version of Python and (2) determine what syntax is allowed.  Am I wrong about that sequence of events?

Comment: @S.Lott No you are not wrong, it just that the difficulty is in including the code somewhere where it will also not be _read_ (parsed) as well as not executed - this isn't immediately apparent as the answers show.

Comment: @Brendan: Difficulty?  The question seems trivial.  Check `sys.version` and write a message has the exact behavior required.  If the version is proper, either use `execfile` or spawn a separate Python subprocess.  I still don't see how this is a problem, or even interesting.

Comment: S.Lott, you can't execute your test in the old version of python because it doesn't compile.  Instead, you get a generic syntax error.  Try the example code with a 2.4 interpreter and you'll see that you can't get to the version test.

Comment: @Mark Harrison: What?  A three line, `import sys; if sys.version_info > ( 2, 4, 0, None, None ): execfile('the real script')` seems like it would work in just about every version of Python ever shipped.  What's going to get a syntax error in that three-line wrapper?  I'm totally lost.

Comment: @S.Lott Well it depends on what you consider trivial - personally I wouldn't consider creating separate files for different versions of Python or spawning extra processes trivial. I would say this question is valuable, especially when you consider Python is full of neat and often surprising tricks - I came here from Google wanting to know if there was a neat answer

Comment: @Brendan:  Two files **is** trivial.  That's why I can't understand the question.

Comment: @S.Lott, everything works fine using the solution in orip's answer.

Comment: @Mark Harrison:  Does that mean that the question is simply "How to check the version of Python in a script?"  If so, it seems trivial. Further, it seems like @orip solution is too complex, since the version number would provide this information more clearly prior to doing the import.  I guess I'm unable to understand why a trivial check against the version number can't be done, and a somewhat more complex `try` block is better.

Comment: @S.Lott, the first conditional in my program is checking the version number, so the question is not how to check the version number.  Type in the example program, run it with python 2.4, then fix the program so you don't get SyntaxError.  Post your answer and I'll follow up there if there's any more confusion.

Comment: @Mark Harrison: The example program is ill-advised and cannot ever work.  A simple change to write a wrapper leads to a program which can work. Since the example can't possibly work, and the wrapper is something you've already proposed, I'm unable to get the question.

Comment: I think we've reached an end of this discussion.  I asked a question about something I didn't know how to do, and got an answer telling me how to do it.  I'm not proposing anything, I just accepted orip's answer which is working great for me (actually the coworker for whom I'm channeling). Viva Le Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can test using `eval`:

```
try:
  eval("1 if True else 2")
except SyntaxError:
  # doesn't have ternary
```

Also, `with` *is* available in Python 2.5, just add `from __future__ import with_statement`.

EDIT: to get control early enough, you could split it into different `.py` files and check compatibility in the main file before importing (e.g. in `__init__.py` in a package):

```
# __init__.py

# Check compatibility
try:
  eval("1 if True else 2")
except SyntaxError:
  raise ImportError("requires ternary support")

# import from another module
from impl import *
```

Comment: this is a fantastic answer.  the main issue from the question that needed addressing is that a program must be syntactically correct for that version of python to even begin executing, so using new syntax precludes a program from starting on older versions of the interpreter.  eval works around that

Comment: If the package is being installed by setuptools, byte-compiling the source files will fail then. Also, all the contortions to produce a run-time error message seem a little pointless -- why not just document the requirements and leave it at that?

Comment: Note that if attempting to check an expression, rather than a simple statement, you need to use `exec` instead of `eval`.  I had this come up while trying to write a function that would print to stderr in both py2k and py3k.

Comment: I think a cleaner version of this solution would be to put your "checks" in a separate module and import that (wrap the `import` station in try/except). Note that you might need to check for other things than `SyntaxError` as well (eg. builtin functions or additions to the standard library)

Answer (score 109):

Have a wrapper around your program that does the following.

```
import sys

req_version = (2,5)
cur_version = sys.version_info

if cur_version >= req_version:
   import myApp
   myApp.run()
else:
   print "Your Python interpreter is too old. Please consider upgrading."
```

You can also consider using `sys.version()`, if you plan to encounter people who are using pre-2.0 Python interpreters, but then you have some regular expressions to do.

And there might be more elegant ways to do this.

Comment: FYI, "cur_version >= req_version" should work as the conditional.

Comment: `sys.version_info` is not a function.

Comment: Putting code inside the successfull conditional like that is pretty bad practice as it is an unecessary indentation and addition of logic. Just do a: if sys.version_info[:2] < req_version: print "old"; sys.exit() - and otherwise continue as usual.

Comment: It's like Tim Peters says in "The Zen of Python": "Flat is better than nested." (You can see this by typing "import this" in python)

Comment: @ChristopherShroba Thank you for `import this`. A lovely diversion.

Answer (score 34):

Try

```
import platform
platform.python_version()
```

Should give you a string like "2.3.1". If this is not exactly waht you want there is a rich set of data available through the "platform" build-in. What you want should be in there somewhere.

Comment: -1: This doesn't work, as explained in the updated question. If you use any syntax from a newer version of Python then your file won't compile, and if it doesn't compile it can't run and check the version!

Comment: @ScottGriffiths Run `print(platform.python_version())` instead of `platform.python_version()`!

Comment: @ScottGriffiths Also checkout my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40633458/5157221.

Answer (score 22):

Probably the best way to do do this version comparison is to use the `sys.hexversion`. This is important because comparing version tuples will not give you the desired result in all python versions.

```
import sys
if sys.hexversion < 0x02060000:
    print "yep!"
else:
    print "oops!"
```

Comment: I think this is most elegant, but probably not the easiest to understand by other devs.

Comment: Can you explain in what circumstances comparing version tuples will not give the desired result?

Comment: version tuples can contain alphanumeric values also.

Comment: -1: This doesn't work, as explained in the updated question. If you use any syntax from a newer version of Python then your file won't compile, and if it doesn't compile it can't run and check the version!

Comment: On which version/platform does this fail?

Answer (score 15):

```
import sys    
# prints whether python is version 3 or not
python_version = sys.version_info.major
if python_version == 3:
    print("is python 3")
else:
    print("not python 3")
```

Comment: Be aware that in Python 2.6 and below, `sys.version_info` is **not** a named tuple. You'll need to use `sys.version_info[0]` for the major version number, and `sys.version_info[1]` for the minor.

Answer (score 9):

> Answer from Nykakin at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505081/what-version-of-python-do-i-have):

You can also check Python version from code itself using `platform` module from standard library.

There are two functions:

- `platform.python_version()` (returns string).
- `platform.python_version_tuple()` (returns tuple).

---

### The Python code

> Create a file for example: `version.py`)

Easy method to check version:

```
import platform

print(platform.python_version())
print(platform.python_version_tuple())
```

You can also use the `eval` method:

```
try:
  eval("1 if True else 2")
except SyntaxError:
  raise ImportError("requires ternary support")
```

---

Run the Python file in a command line:

```
$ python version.py 
2.7.11
('2', '7', '11')
```

The output of Python with CGI via a WAMP Server on Windows 10:

[image: Screenshot 2016-11-16 14.39.01 by Suriyaa Kudo]

---

### Helpful resources

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/505081/what-version-of-python-do-i-have

Answer (score 8):

Sets became part of the core language in Python 2.4, in order to stay backwards compatible. I did this back then, which will work for you as well:

```
if sys.version_info < (2, 4):
    from sets import Set as set
```

Comment: better to check for the feature instead of the version, no? `try: set except NameError: from sets import Set as set`

Comment: @orip: Why? If you know in which version a feature has been introduced, like sets here, just use above code. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 7):

Although the question is:
*How do I get control early enough to issue an error message **and exit**?*

The question that I answer is:
*How do I get control early enough to issue an error message **before starting the app***?

I can answer it a lot differently then the other posts.
Seems answers so far are trying to solve your question from within Python.

I say, do version checking before launching Python. I see your path is Linux or unix.
However I can only offer you a Windows script. I image adapting it to linux scripting syntax wouldn't be too hard.

Here is the DOS script with version 2.7:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM see http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%G IN ('"python.exe -V 2>&1"') DO ECHO %%H | find "2.7" > Nul
IF NOT ErrorLevel 1 GOTO Python27
ECHO must use python2.7 or greater
GOTO EOF
:Python27
python.exe tern.py
GOTO EOF
:EOF
```

This does not run any part of your application and therefore will not raise a Python Exception. It does not create any temp file or add any OS environment variables. And it doesn't end your app to an exception due to different version syntax rules. That's three less possible security points of access.

The `FOR /F` line is the key.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%G IN ('"python.exe -V 2>&1"') DO ECHO %%H | find "2.7" > Nul
```

For multiple python version check check out url:
http://www.fpschultze.de/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=17

And my hack version:

[MS script; Python version check prelaunch of Python module]
http://pastebin.com/aAuJ91FQ

Comment: For those down votes please don't be afraid to explain reasons why.

Comment: Exactly was I looking for. Thanks! Whats the %%H?

Comment: @Clocker python.exe -V would return a "Python 2.7" string. The console puts "Python" string into %%G and the "2.7" string in the automatically created os var %%H (the next letter after G). Echo %%H | find "2.7" pipes "2.7" into DOS command find "2.7" which sets the error level to 1 if %%H is found in "2.7". That error level, resulting in a 1, from using DOS find command, will allow us to branch to DOS batch label :Python27

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
sys.version
```

will be getting answer like this

> '2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'

here **2.7.6** is version

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, syntax errors occur at compile time, not at run time.  While Python is an "interpreted language", Python code is not actually directly interpreted; it's compiled to byte code, which is then interpreted.  There is a compile step that happens when a module is imported (if there is no already-compiled version available in the form of a .pyc or .pyd file) and that's when you're getting your error, not (quite exactly) when your code is running.

You can put off the compile step and make it happen at run time for a single line of code, if you want to, by using eval, as noted above, but I personally prefer to avoid doing that, because it causes Python to perform potentially unnecessary run-time compilation, for one thing, and for another, it creates what to me feels like code clutter.  (If you want, you can generate code that generates code that generates code - and have an absolutely fabulous time modifying and debugging that in 6 months from now.)  So what I would recommend instead is something more like this:

```
import sys
if sys.hexversion < 0x02060000:
    from my_module_2_5 import thisFunc, thatFunc, theOtherFunc
else:
    from my_module import thisFunc, thatFunc, theOtherFunc
```

.. which I would do even if I only had one function that used newer syntax and it was very short.  (In fact I would take every reasonable measure to minimize the number and size of such functions.  I might even write a function like ifTrueAElseB(cond, a, b) with that single line of syntax in it.)

Another thing that might be worth pointing out (that I'm a little amazed no one has pointed out yet) is that while earlier versions of Python did not support code like

```
value = 'yes' if MyVarIsTrue else 'no'
```

..it did support code like

```
value = MyVarIsTrue and 'yes' or 'no'
```

That was the old way of writing ternary expressions.  I don't have Python 3 installed yet, but as far as I know, that "old" way still works to this day, so you can decide for yourself whether or not it's worth it to conditionally use the new syntax, if you need to support the use of older versions of Python.

Comment: Seriously? Duplicate your code just so that you can change some minor structures? Yuck. Very yuck. And as for `a and b or c` instead of `b if a else c`, it's not equivalent; if `b` is falsy it will fail, producing `a` rather than `b`.

Comment: I'm not suggesting duplicating code, I'm suggesting creating wrapper functions for version-specific code, whose signatures don't change across versions, and putting those functions in version-specific modules. I'm talking about functions that are maybe 1 to 5 lines long. It's true that a and b or c is not the same as b if a else c in cases where b may evaluate to false. So I guess ifAThenBElseC(a,b,c) in common_ops_2_4.py, would have to be 2 or 3 lines long instead of 1. This method actually reduces your over all code by encapsulating common idioms into functions.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following at the very top of your file:

```
import sys

if float(sys.version.split()[0][:3]) < 2.7:
    print "Python 2.7 or higher required to run this code, " + sys.version.split()[0] + " detected, exiting."
    exit(1)
```

Then continue on with the normal Python code:

```
import ...
import ...
other code...
```

Comment: rather use `sys.version_info < (2, 7)`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this is perfect for me, can you explain why comparing the `sys.version_info` type to a tuple works?

Comment: @jjj `sys.version_info` **used to be** a tuple; for example `(2, 4, 6, 'final', 0)`; only in Python 3 and 2.7 was it changed into a separate type, which is nevertheless comparable with tuples.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I like that approach better than mine... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to test for functionality rather than versions. In some cases, this is trivial, not so in others.

eg:

```
try :
    # Do stuff
except : # Features weren't found.
    # Do stuff for older versions.
```

As long as you're specific in enough in using the try/except blocks, you can cover most of your bases.

Comment: You're right. That's what he asked how to do - sometimes testing for features in version Y doesn't even compile to bytecode in version X, so it can't be done directly.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this question after a quick search whilst trying to solve the problem myself and I've come up with a hybrid based on a few of the suggestions above.

I like DevPlayer's idea of using a wrapper script, but the downside is that you end up maintaining multiple wrappers for different OSes, so I decided to write the wrapper in python, but use the same basic "grab the version by running the exe" logic and came up with this.

I think it should work for 2.5 and onwards. I've tested it on 2.66, 2.7.0 and 3.1.2 on Linux and 2.6.1 on OS X so far.

```
import sys, subprocess
args = [sys.executable,"--version"]

output, error = subprocess.Popen(args ,stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print("The version is: '%s'"  %error.decode(sys.stdout.encoding).strip("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLMNBVCXZ,.+ \n") )
```

Yes, I know the final decode/strip line is horrible, but I just wanted to quickly grab the version number. I'm going to refine that.

This works well enough for me for now, but if anyone can improve it (or tell me why it's a terrible idea) that'd be cool too.

Answer (score 1):

For *standalone* python scripts, the following module docstring trick to enforce a python version (here v2.7.x) works (tested on *nix).

```
#!/bin/sh
''''python -V 2>&1 | grep -q 2.7 && exec python -u -- "$0" ${1+"$@"}; echo "python 2.7.x missing"; exit 1 # '''

import sys
[...]
```

This should handle missing python executable as well but has a dependency on grep. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458528/why-does-this-snippet-with-a-shebang-bin-sh-and-exec-python-inside-4-single-q) for background.

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding on akhan's excellent answer, which prints a helpful message *before* the Python script is even compiled.

If you want to ensure that the script is being run with Python 3.6 or newer, add these two lines to the top of your Python script:

```
#!/bin/sh
''''python3 -c 'import sys; sys.exit(sys.version_info < (3, 6))' && exec python3 -u -- "$0" ${1+"$@"}; echo 'This script requires Python 3.6 or newer.'; exit 1 # '''
```

(Note:  The second line starts with *four* single-quotes and ends with *three* single-quotes.  This may look strange, but it is not a typo.)

The advantage of this solution is that code like `print(f'Hello, {name}!')` won't cause a `SyntaxError` if a Python version older than 3.6 is used.  You'll see this helpful message instead:

```
This script requires Python 3.6 or newer.
```

Of course, this solution only works on Unix-like shells, and only when the script is invoked directly (such as: `./script.py`), and with the proper eXecute permission bits set.

Comment: Can you use `sys.executable` instead of `python3`?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to print a useful message if the user is running your Python 3 script with a Python 2 exe:

Put this as the first line of code:

```
f' Error: This script requires Python 3.6 or later.'
```

It does nothing in Python 3.6+ (when f-strings were introduced) but fails to compile in Python 2, and prints on the console:

```
  File "test.py", line 34
    f' Error: Error: This script requires Python 3.6 or later.'
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `sys.hexversion` or `sys.version_info`.

`sys.hexversion` isn't very human-friendly because it's a hexadecimal number. `sys.version_info` is a tuple, so it's more human-friendly.

Check for Python 3.6 or newer with `sys.hexversion`:

```
import sys, time
if sys.hexversion < 0x30600F0:
    print("You need Python 3.6 or greater.")
    for _ in range(1, 5): time.sleep(1)
    exit()
```

Check for Python 3.6 or newer with `sys.version_info`:

```
import sys, time
if sys.version_info[0] < 3 and sys.version_info[1] < 6:
    print("You need Python 3.6 or greater.")
    for _ in range(1, 5): time.sleep(1)
    exit()
```

`sys.version_info` is more human-friendly, but takes more characters. I would reccomend `sys.hexversion`, even though it is less human-friendly.

I hope this helped you!

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

```
import sys

def testPyVer(reqver):
  if float(sys.version[:3]) >= reqver:
    return 1
  else:
    return 0

#blah blah blah, more code

if testPyVer(3.0) == 1:
  #do stuff
else:
  #print python requirement, exit statement
```

Comment: -1: This doesn't work, as explained in the updated question. If you use any syntax from a newer version of Python then your file won't compile, and if it doesn't compile it can't run and check the version!

Answer (score -3):

The problem is quite simple. You checked if the version was ***less than*** 2.4, not less than ***or equal to***. So if the Python version is 2.4, it's not less than 2.4.
What you should have had was:

```
    if sys.version_info **<=** (2, 4):
```

, not

```
    if sys.version_info < (2, 4):
```

Comment: read paragraph 3, and the update.  you don't to the point of executing this code because your code won't compile on 2.4 if you are using the new language constructs.

Comment: The less than was fine, just missing the eval.