# Starting Python script without explicitly having X11 open

Tags: python, macos, x11, tkinter

I had Python v2.3 on my system. When I wanted to run a Tkinter script I could just use

```
python myscript.py
```

I recently upgraded to Python 2.5 and now I need to have X11 running and the "DISPLAY" environment variable set before I can run any of my scripts. This is bad for me, because I can't distribute any scripts without explicitly stating "if you're running Python > v2.3, you will need to have X11 open before running this script". Is there a way around this? I'm on OS X Tiger.

Comment: Check out this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446052/python-best-way-to-check-for-python-version-in-program-that-uses-new-language-fe

Comment: @John: I don't want the script to fail just because a user has a more recent version of Python...that seems like punishing them for good work.

Comment: I think you would have more luck asking this on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess (and I do...), it sounds like you installed an X11 based version of python and tkinter rather than one that uses the native windowing system on OSX. I think you can safely write your scripts without telling people they have to have X11 running. You merely have to say they have to have a proper environment set up -- either a native version of python+Tkinter or have X11 running and have an X11-based version of python+Tkinter

In other words, this isn't a regression in python that you have to code around, it's just a side effect of your particular installation of python.

Comment: But there's no reason to live with this.  Just install the proper version of python as I explained.  Having to now run with X11 Tk vs the previous native Tk is very user unfriendly and totally unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, agreed! No reason to live with it. My point was to reassure Goose Bumper that it wasn't a regression in Python, just an artifact of what he chose to install.

Answer (score 1):

Install [python2.5](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/) or [python2.6](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.4/) for OS X from python.org.  They use the native Aqua Tk and thus do not require X11 for IDLE or python scripts that use Tkinter.

Comment: That's exactly my problem actually...python2.5 doesn't work. Python 2.3 does.

Comment: If you installed a python.org python, by default it resides at /usr/local/bin/python (actually symlinks to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.n/bin) rather than /usr/bin/python, so make sure your shell $PATH reflects that.  What Python modules do the scripts use?  As far as I know, there is nothing in the Python standard library supplied with those installers that uses X11.

Comment: BTW, if you installed a python2.5 from Fink or possibly MacPorts, they may be built with a Tk that uses X11.  Use the python.org version instead or ensure that their Aqua Tk variants are used.

Comment: That might be it, because I did use MacPorts.

Comment: That's certainly it and that's why I specifically mentioned using python.org pythons.  You *may* be able to get the MacPorts Tk and python2.5 all working on 10.4 with $ sudo port tk +quartz ; you may need to reinstall python to get tkinter rebuilt.  You may just be better off, in this case, using the python.org one and, possibly, installing a newer Tcl/Tk 8.4 from ActiveState.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Python 2.6.4 and I haven't any problem at all running it without a $DISPLAY variable ...

I'm on linux ...