# How to determine python version in Makefile?

Tags: python, makefile

Since python passed to use version 3 as the default there's a need to handle the version2 code execution with the corret python interpreter. I have a small python2 project where I use `make` to configure and install python package, so here's my question: How can I determine python's version inside `Makefile`?

Here's the logic I want to use:
    if (python.version == 3) python2 some_script.py2
    else python3 some_script.py3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
python_version_full := $(wordlist 2,4,$(subst ., ,$(shell python --version 2>&1)))
python_version_major := $(word 1,${python_version_full})
python_version_minor := $(word 2,${python_version_full})
python_version_patch := $(word 3,${python_version_full})

my_cmd.python.2 := python2 some_script.py2
my_cmd.python.3 := python3 some_script.py3
my_cmd := ${my_cmd.python.${python_version_major}}

all :
    @echo ${python_version_full}
    @echo ${python_version_major}
    @echo ${python_version_minor}
    @echo ${python_version_patch}
    @echo ${my_cmd}

.PHONY : all
```

Comment: To support versions prior to 2.5, I used `python -V` instead

Answer (score 10):

Here is a shorter solution. in top of your makefile write:

```
PYV=$(shell python -c "import sys;t='{v[0]}.{v[1]}'.format(v=list(sys.version_info[:2]));sys.stdout.write(t)");
```

Then you can use it with `$(PYV)`

Answer (score 8):

Here we check for python version > 3.5 before continuing to run make recipes

```
ifeq (, $(shell which python ))
  $(error "PYTHON=$(PYTHON) not found in $(PATH)")
endif

PYTHON_VERSION_MIN=3.5
PYTHON_VERSION=$(shell $(PYTHON) -c 'import sys; print("%d.%d"% sys.version_info[0:2])' )
PYTHON_VERSION_OK=$(shell $(PYTHON) -c 'import sys;\
  print(int(float("%d.%d"% sys.version_info[0:2]) >= $(PYTHON_VERSION_MIN)))' )

ifeq ($(PYTHON_VERSION_OK),0)
  $(error "Need python $(PYTHON_VERSION) >= $(PYTHON_VERSION_MIN)")
endif
```

Comment: PYTHON=$(shell which python )

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [here's a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446052/python-best-way-to-check-for-python-version-in-program-that-uses-new-language-fe) in SF about checking the Python version to control new language features.

Comment: In that case, look here: http://old.nabble.com/Detecting-which-Python-version-is-used-by-SIP-and-PyQt-td30033430.html

Answer (score 0):

```make
PYTHON=$(shell command -v python3)

ifeq (, $(PYTHON))
    $(error "PYTHON=$(PYTHON) not found in $(PATH)")
endif

PYTHON_VERSION_MIN=3.9
PYTHON_VERSION_CUR=$(shell $(PYTHON) -c 'import sys; print("%d.%d"% sys.version_info[0:2])')
PYTHON_VERSION_OK=$(shell $(PYTHON) -c 'import sys; cur_ver = sys.version_info[0:2]; min_ver = tuple(map(int, "$(PYTHON_VERSION_MIN)".split("."))); print(int(cur_ver >= min_ver))')
ifeq ($(PYTHON_VERSION_OK), 0)
    $(error "Need python version >= $(PYTHON_VERSION_MIN). Current version is $(PYTHON_VERSION_CUR)")
endif
```