# How do I detect the Python version at runtime?

Tags: python

I have a Python file which might have to support Python versions < 3.x and >= 3.x. Is there a way to introspect the Python runtime to know the version which it is running (for example, `2.6 or 3.2.x`)?

Comment: do `import sys; print(sys.version)` output `3.9.6 (default, Aug 18 2021, 12:38:10) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ]`

Answer (score 734, accepted):

Sure, take a look at [`sys.version`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version) and [`sys.version_info`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version_info).

For example, to check that you are running Python 3.x, use

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("Must be using Python 3")
```

Here, `sys.version_info[0]` is the major version number. `sys.version_info[1]` would give you the minor version number.

In Python 2.7 and later, the components of `sys.version_info` can also be accessed by name, so the major version number is `sys.version_info.major`.

See also [How can I check for Python version in a program that uses new language features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446052/python-best-way-to-check-for-python-version-in-program-that-uses-new-language-f)

Comment: Don't check the value of `sys.version`. Only use it for displaying purposes.

Comment: @iBug please explain why sys.version should not be checked.

Comment: @Almenon `sys.version` is meant to be displayed to users. It's not a program-friendly interface and therefore *Do not extract version information out of it* (as said by Python Documentation).

Comment: @iBug is correct. The documentation specifically says to instead use sys.version_info for our purpose here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version

Comment: The returned value is not an integer, so I had to cast it in order to perform comparison:  `if int(sys.version[0]) < 3:`.

Comment: You can compare it to a tuple like `sys.version_info >= (3,8,5)` or `sys.version_info >= (3,8)`, but note that version 3.8.5 is not *equal* to `(3,8)` because it compares all the values in `version_info`, which are `major, minor, micro, releaselevel, and serial` according to the documentation.

Comment: I find it more readable to use the named attribute: `sys.version_info.major` than to use indexes.

Comment: And what about `PY_VERSION_HEX` ? https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/apiabiversion.html#apiabiversion

Comment: Better to use
 `sys.version_info.major > 2  and   sys.version_info.minor >7`

Answer (score 155):

Try this code, this should work:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

Comment: FYI this works, but the `python_version` function returns a string (e.g. on my system it prints `'3.6.1'`). If you're checking the version in an `if` statement like the OP is, Chris' answer makes much more sense, as you don't have to go through the clunky process of searching the string for the desired info.

This answer is the way to go if you want to log or display the version to be read by a human.

Comment: @NauticalMile Chris's answer also returns a string, he's just indexing into the first character to see if it is `'3'` or not; the same would work here.

Comment: Hoe does this solve the problem better, if not at all?
Using sys.version_info[0] or just sys.version[0] is already enough ...

Comment: If you want each element in the version number as an int, you can use `platform.python_version_tuple()`. This method may be preferable over sys.version_info [because](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.python_version): "unlike the Python sys.version, the returned value will always include the patchlevel"

Comment: @weberc2, Chris's answer doesn't return a string, at least not the `sys.version_info` option.  That is actually a `sys.version_info` type which happens to be indexible.  (Of course, `sys.version` is a `str`.)

Comment: @jdk1.0 Ah, good find. I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 32):

Per [sys.hexversion](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.hexversion) and [API and ABI Versioning](https://docs.python.org/c-api/apiabiversion.html):

```
import sys
if sys.hexversion >= 0x3000000:
    print('Python 3.x hexversion %s is in use.' % hex(sys.hexversion))
```

Comment: As this allows testing both major _and_ minor versions in a single simple and easy-to-read test, I think this is the best answer.

Comment: You can also do something like `if sys.version_info >= (3,6,0)` because tuples are directly comparable.

Comment: @adzenith , I think your answer is the quickest, most concise, and easiest-understand. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add an answer to this question - maybe it's too old, or maybe because it's marked as a duplicate?

Answer (score 21):

Just in case you want to see all of the gory details in human readable form, you can use:

```
from sys import version as python_formatted_version

print(python_formatted_version)
```

Output for my system:

```
3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0]
```

Something very detailed but machine parsable would be to get the `version_info` object from `sys`, instead, and then use its properties to take a predetermined course of action.

For example:

```
from sys import version_info as python_version_info

print(python_version_info)
```

Output on my system:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Answer (score 17):

The best solution depends on how much code is incompatible. If there are a lot of places you need to support Python 2 and 3, `six` is the compatibility module. `six.PY2` and `six.PY3` are two booleans if you want to check the version.

However, a better solution than using a lot of `if` statements is to use `six` compatibility functions if possible. Hypothetically, if Python 3000 has a new syntax for `next`, someone could update `six` so your old code would still work.

```
import six

# OK
if six.PY2:
  x = it.next() # Python 2 syntax
else:
  x = next(it) # Python 3 syntax

# Better
x = six.next(it)
```

http://pythonhosted.org/six/

Answer (score 12):

Here's some code I use with [`sys.version_info`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version_info) to check the Python installation:

```
def check_installation(rv):
    current_version = sys.version_info
    if current_version[0] == rv[0] and current_version[1] >= rv[1]:
        pass
    else:
        sys.stderr.write( "[%s] - Error: Your Python interpreter must be %d.%d or greater (within major version %d)\n" % (sys.argv[0], rv[0], rv[1], rv[0]) )
        sys.exit(-1)
    return 0

...

# Calling the 'check_installation' function checks if Python is >= 2.7 and < 3
required_version = (2,7)
check_installation(required_version)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the scripts compatible with Python2 and 3 i use :

```
from sys import version_info
if version_info[0] < 3:
    from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: This is unnecessary, just add `from__future__ import print_function` without the version check. The import does nothing in Python 3.

Comment: This code doesn’t even work, it’s a `SyntaxError` because `from __future__` imports must occur at the very top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Version check example below.
Note that I do not stop the execution, this snippet just:
- do nothing if exact version matches
- write INFO if revision (last number) is different
- write WARN if any of major+minor are different

```
import sys
import warnings

def checkVersion():
    # Checking Python version:
    expect_major = 2
    expect_minor = 7
    expect_rev = 14
    if sys.version_info[:3] != (expect_major, expect_minor, expect_rev):
        print("INFO: Script developed and tested with Python " + str(expect_major) + "." + str(expect_minor) + "." + str(expect_rev))
        current_version = str(sys.version_info[0])+"."+str(sys.version_info[1])+"."+str(sys.version_info[2])
        if sys.version_info[:2] != (expect_major, expect_minor):
            warnings.warn("Current Python version was unexpected: Python " + current_version)
        else:
            print("      Current version is different: Python " + current_version)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all you are interested in is whether you have Python 2 or 3, a bit hackish but definitely the simplest and 100% working way of doing that would be as follows: 
`python
python_version_major = 3/2*2`

The only drawback of this is that when there is Python 4, it will probably still give you 3.

Comment: This code gives the wrong answers after futurizing it.