# How to detect Python Version 2 or 3 in script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, python-2.x, six

I've written some scripts, which run either only with Version 2.x or some only with Version 3.x of Python.

How can I detect inside the script, if it's started with fitting Python Version?

Is there a command like:

```
major, minor = getPythonVersion()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Python version at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/detect-python-version-at-runtime)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sys.version_info` provides the version of the used Python interpreter.

**Python 2**

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> sys.version_info[0]
2
```

**Python 3**

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> sys.version_info[0]
3
```

For details see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sys.html#sys.version_info).

Comment: @ewerybody I rejected your edit since using the namedtupel attributes does not work in all versions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the six library (https://pythonhosted.org/six/) to make it easier to write code that works on both versions.
(It includes two booleans `six.PY2` and `six.PY3` which indicate whether the code is running in Python 2 or Python 3)

Also in Python 2.6 and 2.7, you can use

```
from __future__ import (print_function, unicode_literals, division)
__metaclass__ = type
```

to enable some of the Python 3 behaviour in a way that works on both 2 and 3.

Comment: This is useful supplementary information but doesn't really answer the question.