# My split function is not working

Tags: python, input, python-2.x, eof

It's giving me eof parsing error. I don't know how to fix that split function. Please help. Thank you.

```
#Is It An Equilateral Triangle?
def equiTri():
    print("Enter three measure of a triangle: ")
    a, b, c = input().split()

    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    c = float(c)

    if a == b == c:
        print("You have an Equilateral Triangle.")
    elif a != b != c:
        print("This is a Scalene Triangle not an Equilateral Triangle.")
    else:
        print("""I'm guessing this is an Isosceles Triangle so definitely 
not
                an Equilateral Triangle.""")
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. It might come from somewhere else in your code. Also your given code is not correctly indented.

Comment: Similarly cannot reproduce the error after correcting the original indentation.

Comment: What do you type as input that gives you this error?

Comment: My input is 5, 5, 5. I also try 5 5 5.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? Please post the code that fails with the exact indentation.

Comment: I know the error now. I did the code in 3. I put in google drive. Went home. Opened it in 2 so of course. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in Python 2 (you should have said which version), and it only occurs when the `input()` prompts you for a triplet of numbers but you press 'Enter' on a totally blank line (other than whitespace).

You can handle that error condition with:

```
try:
    a,b,c = input("Enter three measures of a triangle: ")
else:
    raise RuntimeError("expected you to type three numbers separated by whitespace")
```

(It's more Pythonic and cleaner to use `try...catch` and assume the input-parsing code works (*"EAFP: Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission"*), than to add extra lines to test the input before and after you try to split it, which is looked down on as *"Look before you leap"* code.)

Comment: Error in Python 2 is correct. I just noticed that. Thanks. My code was written in 3.

Comment: Also see [How to detect Python Version 2 or 3 in script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376907/how-to-detect-python-version-2-or-3-in-script) if you want to detect and stop with a clear message if you accidentally run in Python 2.