# Python STDOUT on Windows

Tags: javascript, python, windows

Python on Windows does not use normal STDOUT, so what is going on here?

```
python --version
Python 2.7.15
```

shows a version!  But I can't capture it!

```
python --version > temp.txt
Python 2.7.15
type temp.txt
```

**NOTHING!**

The issue is, I need to do logic depending on the Python version (from JavaScript) and it's been pretty hopeless so far.

Answer (score 3):

Try redirecting stderr to stdout at the same time you redirect stdout to a file:

`python --version 1>temp.txt 2>&1`

Comment: So, I need this to go to STDOUT.   Sending to the file like you have works on the file, but if I try to then get it in STDOUT in the same go, like :
`python --version 1>temp.txt 2>&1 | type temp.txt`  my output will get swallowed.

Comment: Why not `python --version 1>temp.txt 2>&1` first, and then on a new line (new command) do: `type temp.txt`?

Comment: The library I'm using checks one command on Linux/Windows/Mac.  Making a special case for it to run two commands just for some wonky windows bug is possible but not desirable.  Better, would be python + windows behaving properly, second case would be a way to fix up a single command to give me a valid STDOUT.   Worst case is upstream logic for something problematic like we have here.

Comment: I do't whink this is a windows bug. That doesn't work with linux either: `echo hello >/tmp/test | cat` returns nothing. However `echo hello >/tmp/test ; cat /tmp/test` does (two commands on same new line) For windows you could try with `&` or `&&` (`&` always executes right command and `&&` executes if first command ends ok) So `python --version 1>temp.txt 2>&1 & type temp.txt` for example

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Python command to print the version info to stdout:

```
> python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)" > temp.txt
```

After this command, `temp.txt` will contain the version information.

```
> type temp.txt
2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:09) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

If you wanted to get fancier, you could use `sys.version_info` to extract only specific part of the version, like the major number as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079062/7517724. Using the following line will store only the major version number in `temp.txt`:

```
> python -c "import sys;print(sys.version_info[0])" > temp.txt
> type temp.txt
2
```