# Inputs via Python 3's input() being automatically converted to integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm reading in a text file using the command line via input() in Python 3, and lines in the file that appear numerical are being automatically treated as integers, causing errors. My understanding is that input() is not supposed to do any evaluation, and should treat these as strings. What is causing this behavior and how do I prevent it?

EDIT: For a cleaner example, if my code instead simply reads

```
cases = input()
print(type(cases))
```

My input file reads:

```
100
4 2
```

And I type into cmd:

```
script.py < input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

My output file will contain

```
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Good question :)

Comment: You are using python 2. See [how-do-i-detect-the-python-version-at-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/how-do-i-detect-the-python-version-at-runtime)

Comment: What if you `print(cases)` instead?

Comment: Ah, Patrick, you're right. I thought that couldn't be the case because it still printed using the python 3 print. Thanks and solved!

Comment: `print()` is still valid in Python2. Just `(type(cases))` is the same as `type(cases)`

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick Artner is almost certainly correct. Your code should perform as expected in Python 3, but in Python 2 you'd get the result you're seeing instead.

The Python 2 equivalent of Python 3's *input()* is [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), which converts the input to a string as you expect.

**EDIT:** By the way, never ever use [*input()*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in Python 2. It evalutes the user's input, and therefore is unsafe. (What if the input were `os.system("<some really horrible command>")`?) That's why Python 3 replaced it.

Comment: Seriously, don't even write that. You'll be amazed by the amount of people who will try that out.