# How to correctly import modules from a directory on PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script `main.py` which imports various modules from other scripts in the same directory.

With the lines

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I can see that when I run `main.py`, the directory it is in (`binBuild` below) is added to the `PYTHONPATH` along with the python version I am using (`python3.5` from miniconda)

```
['/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/binBuild', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python35.zip', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg']
```

`main.py` contains two options - it can run directly, or, with a flag specified it can call a gui. At this stage main.py runs with no errors.The gui contains various options that can be set and then when processing is started calls back to  `main.py` to start the main run of the code. At this point the code fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/binBuild/GUI/../main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from GlobalParams import GlobalParams
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GlobalParams'
```

If I print the `PYTHONPATH` at this stage I can see that the `PYTHONPATH` now contains two copies of the path to the directory containing `main.py`.

```
['/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/binBuild', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/binBuild', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python35.zip', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/Programmes/MYCODE/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/ms/data5/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

I also notice at this stage it picks up another copy of python (3.7) which is installed elsewhere on the system.

However, python is no longer able to import any of the modules from the `binBuild` directory (where `main.py` is present). Why can python no longer find modules even though they are in a directory on its path. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging I discovered the problem, so I'm just posting what helped me here in case this is useful for others. The clue was in the appearance of the extra python distribution (`/ms/data5/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/`) in the `PYTHONPATH`. Due to a bug in the code the GUI wasn't calling the packaged python (`python3.5`) but the system python.

I detected this by putting the following lines in `main.py`

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

This showed that the python version was changing between running `main.py` to open the GUI and the GUI calling back to `main.py`. The following stack overflow answer was useful in this context:

[How do I detect the Python version at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/how-do-i-detect-the-python-version-at-runtime)