# Why does this Visual Studio Code throw a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, string

I am getting a syntax error only in VSC not in PyCharm.

```py
user = "Hey"
a = f"Hello World {user}"

print(a)
```

Exception:

> File "/var/folders/4p/bxqjj1910_vd05mk0cywnrxr0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 2
>       a = f"Hello World {user}"
>                             ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What's your Python version in VS?

Comment: May be you were using different python version among the IDEs. f-strings are available only from python 3.6 onwards.

Comment: you are running a python version which is below python 3.6 version. Isn't it?

Comment: Using 3.7.4, should be the same version on both!

Comment: That code works find in my VS code with Python 3.7.3.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41588204/6194097) and try this in both IDEs. Then check the versions and update this question accordingly.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera wow ur right, on he bottom left is 3.74, but your statement prints 2.7.10. Sorry I am just a beginner, thought i had the version displayed on the bottom left. How do i properly update in VSC?

Comment: check this [How can I change python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48135624/6194097) or [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have an old version in python. This f-string is available in Python 3.6 or later. Goto this link and upgrade your python version. And set the path to Environmental variables.

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: He already has both versions, that's why it works on PyCharm, the problem is he need to setup VSC to Python 3.* version.