# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' but installed correctly using PIP3 on Python 3.8.5

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Sorry I know this question has come up a bit but I am stumped. Previously working fine code is now no longer working. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling python 3.8.5, setting up new environments, stripping the code back to basics. I've installed and uninstalled BS4 and Beautifulsoup4 dozens of times.

My method is `pip3 install bs4`

The installation goes fine but when I run the  code I get

```
File "/Users/rupertdenton/Desktop/Coding/Anybody/tester.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I triple check python version and it is 3.8.5 and reinstall again with success:

```
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (2.0.1)
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4, bs4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.9.1 bs4-0.0.1
```

But still the code throws the same error. Here is the pared back code which worked fine until about a week ago.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrapecafes(city, area):

    #url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury' #go to the website
    url = f"https://www.broadsheet.com.au/{city}/guides/best-cafes-{area}"
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafe_names)

    cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", }) #scrape the elements
    cafeNamesClean = [cafe.text.strip() for cafe in cafeNames]
```

Comment: Print the python version in the code. Maybe you are using another python run time?

Comment: Which OS do you use ?

Comment: @CatalinaChircu catalina 10.15.6 (19G73)

Comment: @balderman how would I do this?

Comment: @deadant88 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/how-do-i-detect-the-python-version-at-runtime

Comment: `import sys print(sys.version)`

Comment: 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:10:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
[Finished in 0.051s]

Answer (score 0):

if your code is depending on the environment, you need to activate the environment first.

```
. env/bin/activate
```

if `env` is the name of your environment.

Then

```
pip3 install bs4 requests
```

Then run your program.

Comment: Thanks for the response my env is called venv unfortunately still no love ``(venv) (base) ruperts-mbp:anybody [username]$``