# Python's input function returns integer value instead of string

Tags: python

I am very new here and Python programming as well. I am using **Pycharm**. I read in a book that input function returns string value by default. But in my case, it returns integer by default. What is the problem? Please help me. I have written exactly this in pycharm. And it returns integer value directly.

```py
number=input("Enter a number:")                                                     
print(number)                                                                                         
print(type(number))
```

output shows the number correctly that I input. But the type shows **<type 'int'>**.  Please help me.

Comment: Run your code on Python 3, not the dead Python 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Comment: Python version-3.10.1 and Pycharm version 2021.3

Comment: Where do these numbers come from and how exactly are you executing the code?

Comment: @Noor Thats is ONE python running on your system - but not the one that executes this code - that is a python 2 : [how-do-i-detect-the-python-version-at-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/how-do-i-detect-the-python-version-at-runtime)

Comment: Oh Thanks all! My problem is solved. Though I have installed Python 3.10.1 but in Pycharm python 2 was doing it's job. After changing it to Python 3, Problem is solved! Thanks all for your help!!