# defining a function that contains match and case in python

Tags: python, boolean, match, case, boolean-expression

I want to define a function called sleep_in(weekday, vacation). The parameter weekday is True if it is a weekday, and the parameter vacation is True if we are on vacation. We sleep in if it is not a weekday or we're on vacation.

```
sleep_in(False, False) → True  
sleep_in(True, False) → False  
sleep_in(False, True) → True  
sleep_in(True, True) → True
```

here's the function I defined

```
 def sleep_in(weekday, vacation):
   match (weekday, vacation):
    case (False, False):
     return True
    case (True, False):
     return False
    case (False, True):
     return True
    case (True, True):
     return True
```

but I get the following error:

```
invalid syntax (line 2)
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?
Edit:
Here's my full code in Jupiter Notebook!
[Block of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAzXT.jpg)

Comment: What is your python version? It seems to be a Python 3.10 feature, so I assume you are running the code in an old Python interpreter.

Comment: You can use this, to detect it at runtime:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079062/5057078

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me, do you have any other code or is this the only code?

Comment: @Brambor so you mean my code is totally fine?

Comment: @mohsentajdeh I have Python 3.8, so I didn't check it, but @ TJ20201 says it is.

Comment: Convert your sentence literally to code `return not weekday or vacation`

Comment: @Brambor I'm using at least Python 3.10, so that may be why it works for me and not for OP.

Comment: thanks @azro but I already know the answer, the point is to use match & case!

Comment: Note: `sleep_in(1, 1)` will return `None`.

Comment: @Brambor Yeah I need to add case _:
            return "Please fill the blanks with the correct formatting!"
or something like that!

Answer (score 0):

You have not followed the writing rules. You should leave a space the size of a tab.

```
def ...():
        match(...):
                case(...):
...
```