# How to trick shebang to allow multiple parameters?

Tags: bash, shell, shebang

Is it know that most `shebang` implementations will support a single parameter so if you have something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env some-tool-accepting-yaml param1 param2
... (yaml body)
```

It will now work as expected because it will call the tool with "param1 param2" argument instead of splitting it into two arguments.

It seems that one [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e) practice is to use something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
arbitrary_long_name==0 "exec" "/usr/bin/gawk" "--re-interval" "-f" "$0" "$@"
```

Now this approach would make YAML-based script invalid due to the 2nd line, so the only acceptable workaround would be one that is also a comment, starting with "#" too.

Is there a way to bypass this issue too?

Comment: which is the executable to launch is it `python` ? because there's also this related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458528/why-does-this-snippet-with-a-shebang-bin-sh-and-exec-python-inside-4-single-q

Comment: The workaround you are quoting is for awk, not python.

Comment: Are you interested in a workaround for YAML, or a general solution? In the former case, please tell us what executable should ultimately consume the content of the file?

Comment: Workaround for YAML, I already have 3 tools that are using YAML.

Answer (score 3):

A general solution without using polyglot scripts

## launcher.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# first argument to be split
if [[ $- != *f* ]]; then reset=1; fi
set -f
arg=( $1 )
shift
if [[ $reset = 1 ]]; then set +f; fi

# other arguments
arg+=("$@")

# launch command
exec "${arg[@]}"
```

## script

```
#!/path/to/launcher.sh interpreter opts
```

Comment: Thanks but I am still looking for a self-contained solution, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic solution for this problem(unless you are on MacOSX, which can pass multiple parameters in the `shebang` line), but for particular combinations of the requirements you can use shell tricks, like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec yamllint -f colored --no-warnings ${1:+-c ${1}} - <<...
---
(YAML document)
...
```

We are using `HERE-doc` feature of the shell and YAML end-of-document marker `...` to denote where the shell input ends. Please note, that that would work only with the commands that can accept their input from the STDIN.

If the `some-tool` needs filename as the input parameter, you can (ab)use `bash` in-place file implementation feature, where output of the command is passed through the mapped file descriptor:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass ${1:+--extra-vars hostname=${1}} <(tail +3 ${0})
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  vars_prompt:
    - name: hostname
      prompt: "Hostname"
      private: no

  tasks:
(YAML document)
```

We are passing the output of the `tail` command, skipping first 3 lines of this file through the `/dev/fd/xx` file descriptor, which is treated as a normal readable file by `ansible-playbook`.