# Add conditions in code depending on python version

Tags: python

I am currently writing some code on python 3.3. Unfortunately some of the plugins I rely on are not yet compatible with Python3 and I need to switch back to Python2.7.

In order to avoid refactoring all the code, I would like to do something like

```
if(os.python.version<3.0):
from _future_ import print, super
```

What is the proper way of doing this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446052/python-best-way-to-check-for-python-version-in-a-program-that-uses-new-language

Comment: You can use `from __future__ import print_function` unconditionally, but very many changes do not have an easy future import to resolve them. Porting your program will require more work than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the wrong track here, on several counts.  First, don't check for versions, check for features.  The link @dave you in his comment does a good job of explaining that.

Second, if you did check for versions, and even if there weren't multiple spelling errors, this wouldn't work at all:

```
if(os.python.version<3.0):
    from _future_ import print, super
```

A `__future__` statement can be preceded *only* by the module docstring, blank lines, comment lines, and other `__future__` statements.  It cannot appear anywhere else - you'll just get a syntax error if you try.

Third, for the example you gave, checking *anything* is pointless.  Near the top of the file,

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

is fine in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.  In Python 3 it simply has no effect.

Comment: [They can also be preceded by the module docstring.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements)

Comment: Thanks!  Edited to add that.  Modules can have docstrings?  LOL ;-)

Comment: doesn't answer the question really..

Answer (score 4):

As zhangyangyu says, you can you sys.version_info to get current python version.

sys.version_info is tuple, I always use the first three element in version comparison like this:

```
if sys.version_info[:3] > (3,0):
    do something
elif sys.version_info[:3] > (2,5,2):
    do something else
```

Or, you can use distutils.version to compare current version with specified version.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/how-to-compare-version-style-strings) is answer about how to use distutils.version.