# Python 3: checking version before syntactic analysis

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to check if my interpreter is using Python 3, *before* parsing the entire file, to print a decent error message otherwise.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446052/python-best-way-to-check-for-python-version-in-a-program-that-uses-new-language), there is an answer regarding Python 2.4 / 2.5. However, when I tried to reproduce the solution in my Python 2.7 / 3.3 environment, it did not work.

For instance, running the following file:

```
try:
  eval("print('', end='')")
except SyntaxError:
  raise Exception("python 3 needed")

print("", end="")
```

Results in the following error:

```
File "test_version.py", line 6
  print("", end="")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That is, `eval` is not evaluated soon enough to prevent the parser from reaching line 6.

Is there another hack that might work here?

Comment: The code posted here would not work on Python 2.4 or 2.5 either; you are using `print()` as a function in the code, so the compiler will throw the exception anyway. Move the `print()` use *out* of this module into a separate module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move code using `print()` as a function to a separate module and make the main script do the testing *only*.

It doesn't matter where in the module the `print()` function call is made, it is a syntax error because you are not using `print` as a statement. You'd put that in a separate module imported *after* your test.

```
try:
    eval("print('', end='')")
except SyntaxError:
    raise Exception("python 3 needed")

import real_script_using_print_function
```

However, in Python 2 you can also add:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top to make `print()` work in Python 2 as well. It is perfectly feasible to write Python code that runs on both Python 2 and 3 if taken care.

Comment: The `from __future__ import print_function` is exactly what I needed. I cannot add another "main" file to replace the current one, but I can add the import and then test the version without errors.

Answer (score 2):

The classic way to check for the version of Python that is running your script is to use the tuple returned by `sys.version_info` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    print("This program needs Python version 3.2 or later")
    sys.exit(1)
```

The reason to enable `print()` as a function through the import from `__future__` is because the script wouldn't parse under Python 3.x if the `print` statement was used.

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: @EvertonAgner Using `sys.version_info` will give you information about the version of Python you are using. This is how you can determine if you are using a version you need - just as a general tip.